# Create a page while installing a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating WordPress plugin and now I want to create a page when the plugin IA installed. Please help me how can I create pages while installing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use WordPress plugin activation hook to add new page called '**register_activation_hook**'. it call when your plugin activated.

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'insert_page' );

function insert_page(){
    // Create post object
    $pageArray = array(
      'post_title'    => 'My Page',
      'post_content'  => 'This is my page.',
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
      'post_author'   => get_current_user_id(),
      'post_type'     => 'page',
    );

    // Insert the post into the database
    wp_insert_post( $pageArray, '' );
}
```